# Get Seq of entities from akka http response based on json array

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm  trying to use Flow like Akka http client and got in troubles with getting Seq of case class objects from json array in http response.

HTTP response:

```
{
 "bars": [],
 "foos": [
   {
    "id": "a7d1ba80-0934-11e9-0ef9-efa612d204a1",
    "type": "manual",
    "color": "green",
   },
   {
    "id": "b7d1ba80-0934-11e9-0ef9-efa612d204a2",
    "type": "semi-manual",
    "color": "white"
   }
 ]
}
```

Cases classes:

```
case class FooResponse(foos: Seq[Foo])
case class Foo(id: String, type: String, color: String)
```

Client I did:

```
private val flow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] = Http().outgoingConnection(host, port)

def getFoos(): Seq[Foo] = {
  val req = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET)
  .withUri(Uri("/api/foo")).withHeaders(headers.Accept(MediaRange(MediaTypes.`application/json`)))

  Source
   .single(req)
   .via(flow)
   .map(response => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[FooResponse])
}
```

As a result I have a Source with Future[FooResponse]. How could I return Seq[Foo] from it as a function result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend changing the return type of `getFoos` from `Seq[Foo]` to `Future[Seq[Foo]]`, in order to stay within the context of a `Future`:

```
def getFoos(): Future[Seq[Foo]] = {
  val req =
    HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET)
      .withUri(Uri("/api/foo"))
      .withHeaders(headers.Accept(MediaRange(MediaTypes.`application/json`)))

  Source
    .single(req)
    .via(flow)
    .map(response => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[FooResponse])
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(fooResponse => fooResponse.map(_.foos))
    .runWith(Sink.head)
}
```

Also, since `type` is a reserved keyword in Scala, you need to wrap it in backticks in the `Foo` case class:

```
case class Foo(id: String, `type`: String, color: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `type` is a keyword (type alias) and should not be used as variable name
2. You need to invoke `onComplete()` method on `Future` an wait for the result. In order to do so we can define a placeholder in `getFoos()` - `var fs: Seq[Foo] = Nil`. To the future we are adding `onComplete(tfr => fs = tfr.get.foos)` and then waiting some time: `Await.result(f, Duration(5000, "millis"))` (up to 5s in this example). Finally we can return what is in our placeholder.

This should do the job:

```
def getFoos(): Seq[Foo] = {
  var fs: Seq[Foo] = Nil
  val req = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET)
  .withUri(Uri("/api/foo")).withHeaders(headers.Accept(MediaRange(MediaTypes.`application/json`)))

  val f = Source
   .single(req)
   .via(flow)
   .map(response => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[FooResponse])
  f.onComplete(tfr => fs = tfr.get.foos)
  Await.result(f, Duration(5000, "millis"))
  fs
}
```